# cURL access denied with amazon aws

Tags: php, curl

Trying to download a webcam image using cURL.

The following returns access denied:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/alertwildfire-data-public/Axis-CupertinoHills/latest_full.jpg';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo $data;
```

The URL comes from this link:

http://www.alertwildfire.org/index.html

Select region then view webcam and right-click to view image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the appropriate "Referer" header

Example:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.alertwildfire.org/blmnv/index.html?camera=Axis-Angel&v=81e002f");
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Referer: http://www.alertwildfire.org/blmnv/index.html?camera=Axis-Angel&v=81e002f'
));
```